# Watermark audio files

Tags: speech, project-ideas

Is there a simple technique to watermark .wav audio files?

So that a third person that receives them could check the authencity of the file.

I'm trying to come with ideas for a school project. So I should mainly use techniques from a first course in digital signal processing (DFT, Spectogram, Cepstrum).

Comment: Search github and google for code examples & answers to help better scope your question. It is too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audio watermarking is a technique that relies on inaudible cues. Humans can't really hear phase differences in low tones, if only because it's often delivered via a single bass speaker (i.e. because the HiFi setup physically eliminates the difference). This allows you to stuff information in the phases of the low-frequency parts of the left and right channel.

Exact details I'll leave to you - it's a school project after all - but you will be able to use the (I)DFT to access this phase information.

Comment: It's up to me to come with some ideas for the project. I just wanted to know if this idea was viable. Thanks !

Comment: I recommend browsing these projects, that have preceded you. https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=audio+watermark